# How to enable chameleonic background using GTK webkit?

Tags: gtk, webkit

I have written the code and Chameleonic background is working with Node Webkit. But it is not working with GTK webkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in which way are you using GTK Webkit? If, for example, combined with python, then this could be of help: http://pastebin.com/bd1NMD4g

Cheers,

Wolf

Comment: I want something like this but this is not the specific thing I want. I would like to execute the command in HTML and color a specific portion of Up-Clock according to the RGB value. I would like to avoid Python if possible(How would python communicate with JS and HTML, in that case? It would probably require creation of localhost or something like that).